# How to share files between administrator and standard account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, file-sharing, standard-user

I have been running windows 7 like forever and I had only one account: Administrator(A). This is the first time I've created a standard account(SA). In my SA I created a simple jpg image and placed it in the desktop of SA. Then, when I came back to my A account, the jpg image was not there. It seems that something is wrong with sharing files between these two accounts. I'm not sure what it is ... I want every files of SA to be accessed by A and vice versa. Can you help me to know how to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you went to do correct location: /Users/(SA account name)/Desktop/

Comment: well, your best bet, is to realign your approach. Data shared between users should not be stored inside a users home. Shortcuts to other locations are often a good way to achieve this without losing convenience. Otherwise, what you describe is not normal. you can restrict a folder such that people can't look in it. but in windows, you can't make a file just disappear based on permissions. confirm that the file is not hidden, and view settings are not different between accounts.  if you really want to, everything you want can be handled by granting full control to both users on both homes.

Comment: You have to put the image in a public folder. You cannot share the desktop unless you nav to that folder in WinExplore and set up the properties as Shared.

Answer (score 0):

Open Window Explorer. Navigate to desired folder (Desktop say), from the account you wish to share. For example, you'd like to share your desktop folder with the Admin account.

1) You've navigated to desired folder that you'd like to share.

2) Right-click the folder that you'd like to share and select properties.

3) Select advanced and mark the box "shared".

[image]